# Connecting two server in socket

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

I am a newbie in socket programming but i have a trouble that i have two server started on my localhost on port 3500 and 5000.Now i want thatmy client fist connect to the port 3500 perform some operation and then disconnect from 3500 while server will be running only client wil disconnect from 3500 and the it will connect to port 5000 and agian perform some operations.

I am using the below code to do this but getting error:-

```
import socket

s=socket.socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',3500))
print("connectd to 3500")
print("hello friends")
s.close()
print("disconnect from 3500")
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',5000))
print("connected to 5000")
s.close()
```

But it is not able to connect to the second connection i.e port 5000.It gets connected to port 3500 successfully but while connecting to 5000 it throws an error.
Please any one to short out my mistake

Error:-

```
File "C:\Users\Lal rishav\Desktop\HubPort\test.py", line 9, in <module>
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',5000))
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
```

Comment: both the server is running correctly.The second server is always throwing error either it is port 3500 or port 5000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You cannot do any operations on a `close`d socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close), create a new one instead.

```
s.close()
# the socket is closed, you can't use it anymore!

# get another one:
s2 = socket.socket()
s2.connect(('127.0.0.1',5000))
s2.close()
# now s2 is closed, you can't use it anymore!
```